# Why does C++17's std::any not allow returning a movable value by any_cast?

Tags: c++, std, move-semantics, c++17

While implementing C++17's `std::any` according to the specification available [in this Wiki](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) I stumbled across something that seemed nonsensical to me:

[In the definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) of the free function `std::any_cast`, which is used to retrieve values from an `std::any` instance, an overload for **r-value** references is supplied (It's the third one):

```
template< class ValueType >
ValueType any_cast(any&& operand); // (3)
```

Now, there is a requirement listed below the synopsis that applies to overloads 2 and 3 (that means also including the r-value overload):

> `2-3)` Returns `*any_cast<std::remove_reference_t<ValueType>>(&operand)`

The definition **does not seem to actually allow** moving the data!

The function call is just redirected to the pointer-based overload; the information about the temporary nature of `operand` **is lost!**

**Is it intended that I can't move out of an any instance? Is it just a error in the wiki? Am I wrong here?**

Comment: Related: http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2509

Comment: "Ready - The LWG has reached consensus that the issue is a defect in the Standard, the Proposed Resolution is correct, and the issue is ready to forward to the full committee for further action as a Defect Report (DR).

Typically, an issue must have a proposed resolution in the currently published issues list, whose wording does not change during LWG review, to move to the Ready status."

Comment: SO won't seem to accept the `c++17` tag on this, so feel free to reject my 2nd attempt to add it. They're synonyms, and `c++1z` is set as the master. That seems wrong... but I begrudgingly accept @Yakk's caveat, given past evidence ;-)

Comment: @underscore_d [tag:C++17] has not been published quite yet.  Maybe there will be a meteor strike at the next meeting, and they'll push it back to 2018.  Until then, it is [tag:C++1z]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is in **WP** status at the time of writing this, [which means](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/lwg-active.html):

> WP - (Working Paper) - The proposed resolution has not been accepted as a Technical Corrigendum, but the full WG21/PL22.16 committee has voted to apply the Defect Report's Proposed Resolution to the working paper.

See the lwg here for more info: http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2509

A proposed resolution is indeed

> For the third form, if `is_move_constructible_v<ValueType>` is true and `is_lvalue_reference_v<ValueType>` is false, `std::move(*any_cast<remove_reference_t<ValueType>>(&operand))`, otherwise, `*any_cast<remove_reference_t<ValueType>>(&operand)`

And the defect report list listing the WP: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2509

Comment: @T.C. Thanks. Updating.

Comment: @TC. to those who don't understand every 2 letter acronym, it appears that [WP](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#WP) is the state after [DR](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#DR) where the committee has folded the change into the working paper (ie, it is an "accepted" defect report in a sense?  But not so accepted that it is 100% certain to be going into the next standard, only 99.9%?), but I don't understand meta-standardese well enough to be certain if I read those definitions right.

Comment: @Yakk - WP means that the change is added to a *draft* of the next standard. As committed to the github. The 0.1% risk is that sometimes later another change will overlap and make a new edit to the same part. Who knows?

Comment: @BoPersson and, to be clear, the next standard is C++1z still?  :)

Comment: It's WP for libfun2, though, not for C++1z

Comment: @Yakk That didn't ping. LWG doesn't use "DR" status; everything voted in since the previous standard will be "WP" (for **w**orking **p**aper).

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `std::any` that doesn't require copying is perfectly possible to do. There's only one problem: what do you do when the user requests a copy of `std::any`? One solution to this problem is to make `std::any` move-only, the other is to make it throw an exception on copy constructor if the underlying type is move-only, yet another is to require being able to copy the underlying type. The third solution was chosen.

The requirements placed on `ValueType` being copy constructible are perfectly fine - since a type that's not copy constructible can't possibly be stored in the `std::any` instance, `std::any_cast` may as well make an always-failing cast a compiler error.

Now, the fact that the implementation of `ValueType any_cast(any&& operand)` doesn't allow moving seems to be an oversight - after all, a copy is a perfectly fine implementation of moving, and the implementation is free to delegate the job to the move constructor if it's there, and to copy constructor if not.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the specific question being asked